# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar datos de forma iterable en mi pagina usando nextjs?

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs, nextjs13

Tengo un componente en mi proyecto en NEXTJS que es una tabla que quiero mostrar en mi pagina. Ya obtengo el JSON que necesito para saber los valores que tendrá mi tabla, el problema es que no los muestra. No sé qué sucede.

Codigo del componente de la tabla:

```
import styles from "./table.module.css";

export default function Table(data) {
  let listsElements = data.data;

  return (
    <section className={styles.container}>
      <header className={styles.header}>
        <h1 className="font-bold">USUARIOS</h1>
      </header>
      <table
        className={`${styles.table} w-full text-left table-auto min-w-max`}
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="p-4 border-b border-blue-gray-100 bg-blue-gray-50">
              <p
                className={`${styles.title} font-bold block font-sans text-sm antialiased leading-none text-blue-gray-900 opacity-70`}
              >
                Nombre
              </p>
            </th>
            <th className="p-4 border-b border-blue-gray-100 bg-blue-gray-50">
              <p
                className={`${styles.title} font-bold block font-sans text-sm antialiased leading-none text-blue-gray-900 opacity-70`}
              >
                Apellido
              </p>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {listsElements &&
            listsElements.map((element) => {
              console.log(element);
              <tr key={element._id} className="even:bg-blue-gray-50/50">
                <td className="p-2">
                  <p className="block font-sans text-sm antialiased font-normal leading-normal text-blue-gray-900">
                    {element.nombre}
                  </p>
                </td>
                <td className="p-2">
                  <p className="block font-sans text-sm antialiased font-normal leading-normal text-blue-gray-900">
                    {element.apellido}
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>;
            })}
          <tr>
            <td className={styles.lastRow}></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  );
}
```

La información se muestra por consola, pero nada que consigo que salga en mi página. Ayuda :(

Comment: al <tr> dentro del map te falta ponerle un return... `return <tr>...`

Comment: Tal como dice el compañero Pipe, si en una arrow function usas llaves ( `{}`) debes especificar qué es lo que quieres devolver con un `return` en la línea que toca (en este caso, el `<tr>`). Solo se omite cuando no añades corchetes: `xxx.map(dato => <tr>...</<tr>)`, porque en este caso solo hay una única cosa en el mapeo, y eso es lo que se devuelve. Pero si tienes múltiples líneas (con las llaves) debes poner el return si o si!

Comment: ahora sí funciona. Muchas gracias!